# Knockout binding not updating after dragging the text with mouse in firefox

Tags: html, data-binding, input, knockout.js

I have one simple textbox and span binded with the knockout observable like this

```
function ViewModel(){
var self=this;
self.name=ko.observable();
}
```

and

```
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"/>
  <br/>
  <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
  <h2>dragdata</h2>
```

here is the fiddle for this http://jsbin.com/UqugasE/3/edit

Now when I drag some text from some source and put it into the textbox and lose focus the binding is updating only in Chrome and Ie9+, but it is not working in firefox(25.0)..

I think that in firefox the value is only updating after user have key interaction with the input box and lose focus..

Any idea or solution for this..

P.S
I can update the value of the binding with

> valueUpdate:'input'

but I just wanted to know the reason why it is not working with firefox.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a know bug :
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/683

It's caused by FF does'nt support values update event (change event) like others.

As you said, you can do it with the valueUpdate databindingHandlers.

```
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate:'input'"/>
```